# How to add Search and Filter Criteria in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, search, yii, filter

I am developing a database application using Yii Framework. I am reading tables from MySQL database and displaying them to the user. I need the user to be able to filter the fields in the table or search for a certain value.

For example, I have a table named "supermarkets":

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `supermarkets` (
  `Name` varchar(71) NOT NULL,
  `Location` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Telephone` varchar(68) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Fax` varchar(29) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Website` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

.../model/supermarkets:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Supermarkets extends ActiveRecord
{



}
```

.../views/supermarkets/index.php:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\LinkPager;
?>
<h1>Supermarkets</h1>
<ul>
<?php
$array = (array) $supermarkets;

function build_table($array){

    // start table

    $html = '<table class="altrowstable" id="alternatecolor">';

    // header row

    $html .= '<tr>';

    foreach($array[0] as $key=>$value){

            $html .= '<th>' . $key . '</th>';

        }

    $html .= '</tr>';

    // data rows

    foreach( $array as $key=>$value){

        $html .= '<tr>';

        foreach($value as $key2=>$value2){

            $html .= '<td>' . $value2 . '</td>';

        }

        $html .= '</tr>';

    }

    // finish table and return it

    $html .= '</table>';

    return $html;

}



echo build_table($array);

?>
```

....Controllers/SupermarketsController:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;

use yii\data\Pagination;
use app\models\Supermarkets;
class SupermarketsController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $query = supermarkets::find();

        $pagination = new Pagination([
            'defaultPageSize' => 20,
            'totalCount' => $query->count(),
        ]);

        $supermarkets = $query->orderBy('Name')
            ->offset($pagination->offset)
            ->limit($pagination->limit)
            ->all();

        return $this->render('index', [
            'supermarkets' => $supermarkets,
            'pagination' => $pagination,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I need the user to be able to filter the table or search its fields by one or more attribute. How can I do this?

Comment: Two things that worth mention about your database table are:

 1. Do not capitalize column names.
 2. Use a 'id' field to uniquely identify the supermarket. This can be a autoincrement column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of trying to reinvent the wheel you can simply use the Yii provided [CGridView widget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView). It has the sorting and filtering functionality. Check the documentation and you will find that there are lot of configurations you can play with. Following code snippet uses minimum configuration.

.../views/supermarkets/index.php:

```
    <?php
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id' => 'supermarkets-grid',
        'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
        'filter' => $model,
        'columns' => array(
            'name',
            'location',
            'telephone',
            'fax',
            'website'
        ),
    ));
    ?>
```

Implement search() function in Supermarkets model.

```
public function search()
{

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
    $criteria->compare('location',$this->location,true);
    $criteria->compare('telephone',$this->telephone,true);
    $criteria->compare('fax',$this->fax,true);
    $criteria->compare('website',$this->website,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort'=>array(
            'defaultOrder'=>'name ASC',
        ),
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>20
        ),
    ));
}
```

Controllers/SupermarketsController:.

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $model =new Supermarkets('search');
    if(isset($_GET['Supermarkets']))
        $model->attributes =$_GET['Supermarkets'];

    return  $this->render('index', array('model'=>$model));
}
```

Comment: I can't use CDbcriteria in yii2, any suggestions?

Comment: CDbCriteria class is replaced by ActiveQuery in Yii 2. You can use it to build a query. Or you can set up a Search model as  mentioned in following wiki. http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/#hh12

Answer (score 1):

The right and better way to organize all queries and filtering in your Model class rather than in controller.

You should use `findAll()` rather than `find()` - to find all records that meet your criteria. `find()` - limited to return only one record.

You could do what you need in different ways:

1. Just make string SQL-criteria to search through necessary attributes:

   findAll('Name = "Supermarket" OR Telephone = "99988899"')

// searches supermarket with name "Supermarket" or with telephone - "99988899" (without qoutes)

2. Good Yii way use CDbCriteria:

$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
// add any atributes that you want to filter
$criteria->addCondition('Name = "Supermarket"');
$criteria->addCondition('Telephone = "99988899"','OR');

and use findAll like findAll($criteria).

Finally - just read the Yii manual about Models and working with ActiveRecord. It's documentation is quite good and easy to understand.